# Devise - how to change setting so that email addresses don't need to be unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I set up Devise to log in with a username instead of email address because a significant number of our users share the same email address with their spouse. It is a unique market that we serve. But each spouse needs separate accounts to record personality instrument results.

The database no longer requires a unique email address so it will accept the same email addy for two accounts. However, Devise is still requiring a unique email address for each account. Is there a setting or a work around that i can use to change this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in the `config/initializers/devise.rb`. You can change the default authentication key, which by default is `:email` to be anything you want, for example:

`config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`

Comment: I already did that. Devise is still requiring a unique email address. Thanks for your initiative though.

Comment: In that case, remove :validatable from the model and you should be fine. Add your own custom validations if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately removing `:validatable` removes a lot of other useful stuff, e.g. password validation.  In recent versions of Devise you can also implement `email_required?` on your model.  This will skip email validation if `false` is returned, see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/545

Comment: I dont want to remove validatable, because, then we have to write all the password validation. I made both the changes mentioned above (in initializers and email_required? method with false),But it didn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 54):

• Jimmy these methods on your user model (whatever model is mounted with Devise) Note that the devise uniqueness methods are simply defined with an `if:` modifier so all you're doing is forcing it not to run

***for devise 4.2.1 or below***

```
    def email_required?
      false
    end
      
    def email_changed?
      false
    end
```

***For Devise 4.3.0 or higher***

```
    def will_save_change_to_email?
      false
    end
```

*Please take note you are "monkeypatching" a private API so devise might change its method for this in the future. Be sure to have good test coverage on this to guard against a change in Devise's API*

***Migration***

Remove the database index that enforces uniqness:
rails g migration update_index_on_users
def up
sql = 'DROP INDEX index_users_on_email'
sql << ' ON users' if Rails.env == 'production' # Heroku pg
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end

• Be sure to re-implement validation to suite your needs

Comment: what Erik Jacobs writes below validated this approach, since the validation he commented out can be disabled by `email_changed?`. I slightly prefer what Moin Haidar did here, since you don't need to edit the Devise code this way.

Comment: Migration can be: `remove_index :users, :email`

Answer (score 2):

Please find the instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove `uniqueness validation` given by the `devise` and keep the others, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964557/2177206) (for `rails` >= 4.1.6).

Answer (score -1):

So, this is really old... but I thought I'd respond.

I'm using an old version of devise (1.4.9), but, through some help in #rubyonrails on freenode, I found that you have to edit the  lib / devise / models / validatable.rb:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Validatable
      # All validations used by this module.
      VALIDATIONS = [ :validates_presence_of, :validates_uniqueness_of, :validates_format_of,
                      :validates_confirmation_of, :validates_length_of ].freeze

      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
        assert_validations_api!(base)

        base.class_eval do
          validates_presence_of :email, :if => :email_required?
          # commented out so that we don't check for unique emails
          #validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => (case_insensitive_keys != false), :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
          validates_format_of :email, :with => email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?

          validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required?
          validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_required?
          validates_length_of :password, :within => password_length, :allow_blank => true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This also required going into the database and changing the index on the email column, which is set to unique out of the box.