# Rails Active model validator not accepting :on => :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a User model and for that i have used a custom validator class and the code for custom validator class is given as

**user_validator.rb**

```
class UserValidator
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email, :id
  validates :first_name, :presence => {
                           :message => I18n.t("users.errors.first_name_blank")
                       }
  validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 64 , :message => I18n.t("users.errors.first_name_length")

  validates :last_name, :presence => {
                          :message => I18n.t("users.errors.last_name_blank")
                      }
  validates_length_of :last_name, :maximum => 64, message: I18n.t("users.errors.last_name_length")
  validates :email, :presence => {
                      :message =>  I18n.t("users.errors.email_blank")
                  }, format: {
                      with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i,
                      message: I18n.t("users.errors.email_format")
                  }, :on => :create
  validate :email_uniqueness

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  private

  def email_uniqueness
    if self.id.blank?
      unless User.where(email: email).count == 0
      errors.add(:email, I18n.t("users.errors.email_taken"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this custom validator class i have used in update and create action but in update action i am not using the email validation how can i use the email validation only on create , unfortunately rails is not accepting :on => :create in this

Comment: any reason why are you using custom validator? otherwise in one line your work will be done. eg. validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create

Comment: this is because rails is not accepting the :on => :create in the ActiveModel::Validations , i dont know why

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: Yeah just out of curiosity, how come you are not simply doing `validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :create` ?

Comment: i am using rails 4.2.1

Comment: You should really whitelist your accepted attributes also, instead of using attr_accessor.

Comment: this issue belongs to devise please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097921/devise-how-to-change-setting-so-that-email-addresses-dont-need-to-be-unique

Comment: @user4965201: Your example is a plain Ruby class and does not inherit from `ActiveRecord`. How do you define `on: :create` or `on: :update` in this context if there is no persistence layer?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass hashes to the validator options then the `:on` condition has to be part of the hashes:

```
validates :email, 
  presence: {
    message:  I18n.t("users.errors.email_blank"),
    on: :create
  }, 
  format: {
    with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i,
    message: I18n.t("users.errors.email_format"),
    on: :create
  },
  uniqueness: { 
    on: :create 
  }
```

See the [`:email` example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
validates :email, :presence => {
                  :message =>  I18n.t("users.errors.email_blank")
              }, format: {
                  with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i,
                  message: I18n.t("users.errors.email_format")
              }, :if => :new_record?
```

Comment: i am getting NoMethodError (undefined method `new_record?' for UserValidator:Class):

Comment: You cannot provide a block like that: You would have to provide a `Proc` that takes an argument (`if: Proc.new { |user| user.new_record? }`) or use a simple symbol (`id: :new_record?`)

Answer (score 0):

If authentication is done with email using devise then you can't override it.

```
     # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email.
```

You need to change it to :username or something else.
You can't accept same email again on update, devise will not allow you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement your validation in my code, and it's working absolute fine.

```
validates :email, :presence => {
                      :message =>  I18n.t("users.errors.email_blank")
                  }, format: {
                      with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i,
                      message: I18n.t("users.errors.email_format")
                  }, :on => :create
```

I got this error on create:

```
2 errors prohibited this admin_about_me from being saved:
Story title translation missing: en.users.errors.email_blank
Story title translation missing: en.users.errors.email_format
```

and it successfully saved on update.

I think you want to check email uniqueness on update as well.

you should use this:

```
validates :email, 
  presence: {
    message:  I18n.t("users.errors.email_blank"),
    on: :create
  }, 
  format: {
    with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i,
    message: I18n.t("users.errors.email_format"),
    on: :create
  }
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

Use below line for create or update

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :update
validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :create
```

Comment: maybe you are trying in your model , i am doing this by making a new class and not inheriting ActiveRecord::Base